# Pyqt command line options

Tags: pyqt4

I cannot find any references to command line arguments for pyqt, such as:

-style windows
-background "yellow"

I've only found a couple by accident.

Hasn't helped to Google it or use Qt Assistant.  (Unless it's well hidden)

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 6):

From the PyQt4 manual entry for QApplication:
([http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qapplication.html)](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qapplication.html)

> **All Qt programs automatically support
> the following command line options:**
>
> -style= style, sets the application GUI style. Possible values are motif,
> windows, and platinum. If you compiled
> Qt with additional styles or have
> additional styles as plugins these
> will be available to the -style
> command line option.
>
> -style style, is the same as listed above.
>
> -stylesheet= stylesheet, sets the application styleSheet. The value must
> be a path to a file that contains the
> Style Sheet. Note: Relative URLs in
> the Style Sheet file are relative to
> the Style Sheet file's path.
>
> -stylesheet stylesheet, is the same as listed above.
>
> -session= session, restores the application from an earlier session.
>
> -session session, is the same as listed above.
> -widgetcount, prints debug message at the end about number of widgets left
> undestroyed and maximum number of
> widgets existed at the same time
>
> -reverse, sets the application's layout direction to Qt.RightToLeft
>
> -graphicssystem, sets the backend to be used for on-screen widgets and
> QPixmaps. Available options are raster
> and opengl.
>
> -qmljsdebugger=, activates the QML/JS debugger with a specified port. The
> value must be of format
> port:1234[,block], where block is
> optional and will make the application
> wait until a debugger connects to it.

> **The X11 version of Qt supports some
> traditional X11 command line options:**
>
> -display display, sets the X display (default is $DISPLAY).
>
> -geometry geometry, sets the client geometry of the first window that is
> shown.
>
> -fn or -font font, defines the application font. The font should be
> specified using an X logical font
> description. Note that this option is
> ignored when Qt is built with
> fontconfig support enabled.
>
> -bg or -background color, sets the default background color and an
> application palette (light and dark
> shades are calculated).
>
> -fg or -foreground color, sets the default foreground color.
>
> -btn or -button color, sets the default button color.
>
> -name name, sets the application name.
>
> -title title, sets the application title.
>
> -visual TrueColor, forces the application to use a TrueColor visual
> on an 8-bit display.
>
> -ncols count, limits the number of colors allocated in the color cube on
> an 8-bit display, if the application
> is using the QApplication.ManyColor
> color specification. If count is 216
> then a 6x6x6 color cube is used (i.e.
> 6 levels of red, 6 of green, and 6 of
> blue); for other values, a cube
> approximately proportional to a 2x3x1
> cube is used.
>
> -cmap, causes the application to install a private color map on an
> 8-bit display.
>
> -im, sets the input method server (equivalent to setting the XMODIFIERS
> environment variable)
>
> -inputstyle, defines how the input is inserted into the given widget, e.g.,
> onTheSpot makes the input appear
> directly in the widget, while
> overTheSpot makes the input appear in
> a box floating over the widget and is
> not inserted until the editing is
> done.